# SSRS Report Builder3.0: Set Report Property Variable with Dataset Lookup

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I want to set a Report Property Variable to a value from a Dataset using a lookup: Such as:
=Lookup(Fields!HEX.Value), Fields!Title.Value, "Red", "Colors")

If I use the above, I get an error that I am referencing outside of a dataset and that I must use an aggregate. If I convert my fields to an aggregate then I get an error that Lookup does not work with an aggregate.

Use Case: I want to create variables for my reports that point to a common list of colors so that if I change my color value in the list, all of my reports get the new color without having to edit each report individually. I'm using the variable so my multiple expression in my report can refer to the variable and I don't have to embed/maintain the lookup in each expression.

Answer (score 0):

(Leaving the post with this answer in case someone has the same issue.)

I had the syntax of my lookup incorrect, the correct order of operation is:
=Lookup("Red", Fields!Title.Value, Fields!HEX.Value, "Colors")

Lookup Red in the field called Title and return the value in HEX.